# How to achieve new line display in asp.net 7 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, newline

In my previous WebAPI project before this one, I always achieved multiline display of texts by using the newline.

> \n
> within the string as follows and it worked, displaying the different options on different lines when I return the string as response.

```
 Message= "What do you want to do? \n" +
            "1 Option 1 \n" +
            "2 Option 2 \n" +
            "3 Option 3"
```

But the last I used it was in a dotnet 6 application.

Currently, I am working on a dotnet 7 project and when I do the same thing as above, the options appear in one line in the method response.
I have also tried to use `Environment.Newline` to achieve the newline behaviour but to no avail still.

I have also tried to use StringBuilder as follows:

```
 sb.AppendLine("What do you want to do?");
        sb.AppendLine("1 Option 1 ");
        sb.AppendLine("2 Option 2");
        sb.AppendLine("3 Option 3");

 Message = sb.ToString();
```

Please what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you return the message directly,"\n" would be there in the response body,so the main problem is why your client /browser couldn't display "\n" as new line ,you should let us know what you displayed the string then we could find a solution for you

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I am returning the string as part of a WebAPI response. So, I'm checking on Postman. It is not a browser issue this time

Comment: I'll check with postman and try to found the solution

Comment: It seems you choosed the Preview option instead of pretty option

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $- string interpolation along with Environment.NewLine?

Check the same in console or different browser as sometimes browser might not see it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too to  no avail

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've selected the right option:
[image]

[image]

and for example ,in html

[image]

it makes a new line with the css setting white-space:pre-wrap,if you set like:white-space:nowrap,it would display in a line

Some clients would make a new line with "\r\n" instead of "\n",so it also depend on your client